# Why do from __future__ imports have to be at the top of the file?

Tags: python, import

I personally don't see why `from __future__` imports have to be at the top of the file. All I'm  asking is why, why do they have to be at the top? What's the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can change the language syntax, including but not limited to the behaviour of the `import` statement, thus they must come before anything that they might alter.  In practice, that means at the top of the file (you can have some comments above them, obviously). Here's the link to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future).

Comment: A link to the [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future) would make this an ace answer.

Comment: That line is not required @VladimirPutin